# UserWarning: `Sequential.model` is deprecated

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, sequential

**Log:**

> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py:110:
>
> **UserWarning**: `Sequential.model` is deprecated. `Sequential` is a subclass of `Model`, you can just use your `Sequential` instance
>   directly.  warnings.warn('`Sequential.model` is deprecated. '

*When executing the model in jupyter notebook Its working in `.ipynb` file format but stops working when execute in the VS code in `.py` file format.*

**Code:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding, Flatten, LSTM, Dropout, Conv1D, SpatialDropout1D
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_fatures, embed_dim,input_length = x.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['acc'])
model.summary()
```

**Saving the model:**

```
model.model.save('my_model.h5')
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: There is no need for model.model, just do model.save

Answer (score 0):

The **UserWarning** mentions that, you must use,

```py
# Saving model
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

to save your Sequential model instead of `model.model.save('my_model.h5')`. Since `Sequential().model.save()` is been deprecated.

Comment: Have tried doing the same, the file is getting executed but can't see the Saved "my_model.h5" file in the directory.

Comment: Try saving the model after calling `model.fit()` method. And also use `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`.